# Access main program from shared library in C

Tags: c, shared-libraries

After some googling, I got shared libraries working quite well.  I can open my module with `dlopen` and load functions with `dlsym`.  However, this is always running functions from the library in the program, how do I use functions from my program in the library?

My simplified code:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


int twice(int a){
    return a*2;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
   char *plugin_name;
   void *plugin;
   int (*init)();
   if(argc<2){
      printf("give lib name\n");
      return 0;
   }
   plugin = dlopen (argv[1], RTLD_NOW);
   if (!plugin)
   {
      printf("Cannot load %s: %s\n",argv[1], dlerror ());
      return 0;
   }

  init = dlsym (plugin, "init");
  char * result = dlerror ();
  if (result)
  {
      printf("Cannot find init in %s: %s\n", plugin_name, result);
      return 0;
  }
  int res = init();
  printf("result: %i\n",res);
  return 0;
}
```

plugin.c

```
int init()
{
    return twice(4);
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: main lib

main: main.c
    gcc -ldl -o main main.c

lib: plugin.c
    gcc -shared -o plugin.so plugin.c
```

And I run it with:

```
./main ./plugin.so
```

Comment: There is no generic way to do this. Pass function pointer to the library function, and keep it somewhere. When necessary, call back this function by pointer. This is called `callback` and `callback registration`.

Comment: Or maybe he just want to share code between the application and the plugin. In this case, you could create a shared library containing the shared code.

And you just link your plugin and your application against this library containing common code

Answer (score 0):

With Linux, glibc, and GNU ld you can run `-rdynamic` to your executable link flags. This will make all symbols in your executable visible to loadable modules, as if it were a shared library.

Note that this is not necessarily portable to other Unix-like systems.